# Starter makes no sound

Tags: starting

Starter makes no sound. Battery is very good. Lights , dashboard, side doors, and radio work well. The problem happened suddenly after turning van off (2012 Toyota Sienna)and it sat in the driveway for a couple of days. Can the starter get detached from the battery?Many suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does the vehicle have an immobiliser?

Comment: Do you hear any clicking when you try to turn the starter?

Comment: Open the hood of the van, stick your head out the window, and try to listen for a sound as you turn the key. When you turn the key, the *starter relay* connects the battery to the starter motor. The starter relay is located near the battery and the fuse box/panel. It should make a small "click" sound, similar to the click that turn signals make. If you hear the click, it means that the battery is sending power to the starter motor.

Comment: Do you see anything which looks like a green key amongst the dash lights?

Comment: I do not know what an immobilizer is? How can I know?  Van is in my driveway. The cost of towing plus cost of estimate may not make the tripworth it.

Comment: I do hear a single click infer the hood when I try to start it. All other electrical functions.

Comment: Van DOES have an immobilizer